# Confusion Regarding How to Use Capture Lists to Avoid a Reference Cycle

Tags: swift, closures, retain-cycle

My custom UIViewController subclass has a stored closure property. The closure signature is defined as to take a single argument of the same type of the class:

```
class MyViewController {

    var completionHandler : ((MyViewController)->(Void))?

    // ...
}
```

...the idea being, the object passing itself back as an argument of the handler, a bit [like the UIAlertAction initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertAction_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIAlertAction/actionWithTitle:style:handler:).

In addition, and for convenience, I have a factory(-ish) class method:

```
class func presentInstance(withCompletionHandler handler:((MyViewController)->(Void)))
{
   // ...
}
```

...that performs the following actions:

1. Creates an instance of the view controller,
2. Assigns the completion handler to the property,
3. Presents it modally from whatever happens to be the top/root view controller at the time of the call.

**My view controller is definitely leaking:** I set up a breakpoint on `deinit()` but execution never hits it, even way after I'm done with my view controller and it is dismissed.

I am not sure of how or where I should specify a capture list in order to avoid the cycle. Every example I have come across seems to place it where the closure body is defined, but I can't get my code to compile.

1. Where I declare the closure property? (how?)

   ```
   var completionHandler : ((MyViewController)->(Void))?
   // If so, where does it go?
   ```
2. Where I declare the closure parameter?

   ```
   class func presentInstance(withCompletionHandler handler:((MyViewController)->(Void)))
   {
   // Again, where could it go?
   ```
3. Where I call the above function and pass the closure body?

   ```
   MyViewController.presentInstance(withCompletionHandler:{
       [unowned viewController] viewController in 

       // ...
   })
   // ^ Use of unresolved identifier viewController
   // ^ Definition conflicts with previous value
   ```
4. Where I actually *call* the closure, towards `self`? 
   None of these will compile:

   ```
   self.completionHandler?(unowned self)
   self.completionHandler?([unowned self] self)
   self.completionHandler?([unowned self], self)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out my view controller was being retained by a block, but not the one I was thinking:

```
class MyViewController
{
    deinit(){
        print("Deinit...")
    }

    // ...

    @IBAction func cancel(sender:UIButton)
    {
        completionHandler(self) 
        // View controller is dismissed, AND
        // deinit() gets called.     
    }

    @IBAction func punchIt(sender: UIButton)
    {
        MyWebService.sharedInstance.sendRequest(    
            completion:{ error:NSError? in

                 self.completionHandler(self)  
                 // View controller is dismissed, BUT
                 // deinit() does NOT get called. 
            }
        )
    }
```

...so it is the closure passed to `MyWebService.sharedInstance.sendRequest()` that was keeoing my view controller alive. I fixed it by adding a capture list like this:

```
MyWebService.sharedInstance.sendRequest(    
            completion:{ [unowned self] error:NSError? in
```

*However*, I still don't quite understand why the short-lived completion handler, passed to the web service class, executed once, and disposed, was keeping my view controller alive. That closure, not stored anywhere as a property, should be deallocated as soon as it is exited, right?

I must be missing something. I guess I'm still not fully thinking in <s>portals</s> closures.